# How to pass isystem flag to clangd in compile_commands.json?

Tags: clangd

I have an embedded C project, and want to read it in VSCode with clangd extension. I've built the project and generated compile_commands.json successfully with xmake/cmake. But clangd cannot find (cross compiler's) system headers using the generated compile_commands.json.

According to [clangd documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/system-headers), I need to pass `-isystem` flag to clangd in compile_commands.json. I don't know how. The flags in "arguments" in compile_commands.json are passed to the cross compiler rather than clangd. Run `clangd -isystem <path>` results in "Unknown command line argument '-isystem'". Where should I add the `-isystem` flag?

Comment: "arguments" in `compile_commands.json` is the right place. Clangd doesn't actually execute the commands in `compile_commands.json`, rather it uses them to guide how it should process the code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to pass the -isystem flag to clangd in compile_commands.json by adding the following line to the command field of the relevant JSON object:

css

"-isystem/path/to/system/header/directory"

You can also pass multiple -isystem flags by adding multiple entries to the command field, as shown in the following example:

json

"command": "clang++ -isystem/usr/include -isystem/path/to/other/header/directory file.cpp"

Note that the command field should contain the entire compiler command, including any flags or options you want to pass to clangd.